# Odd Behaviour From jQuery Animate

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using jQuery's animate() function in conjunction with easing from the jQuery UI plugin to animate scrolling down my page with links in a sidebar.  I'm also using it to operate a "back to top" button.  You can see it live here: http://www.element17.com/

The back to top button is working perfectly, but the behaviour of the links is erratic.  Sometimes it works great, and other times it either refuses to scroll, waits a second or two and then scrolls, or doesn't animate at all and just jumps down the page as if they weren't scripted in the first place.

Here's the code for the back to top button:

```
$('#go_up').click(function(){
  $('#main').animate({scrollTop:0}, 2000, 'easeOutExpo');
});
```

And here's the code for the links:

```
$('.scroll').click(function(){
  $('#main').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top}, 3000, 'easeOutExpo');
});
```

I've tested this in Chrome in OSX and Windows, and the behaviour is erratic in both.  Can anyone suggest why this might be the case?

Comment: It is difficult to say just by looking at this code. Try putting console.log into your clicks, including ..offset().top, and add the complete callback where you also log the end of the animation. It will help to determine the sequence of events. Similar scripts worked for me just fine.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this?  I'm not sure how to accomplish what you're saying...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the first you need to prevent the default behavior from hash links (`return false`) and further you need to check if there's an element with the given id.

```
$('a[href*=#]').on('click', function() {
    var hash = $(this.hash).offset();
    if (hash) {
        $('#main').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: hash.top
        }, 3000, 'easeOutExpo');
        return false;
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**
Change your links and ID's to valid ones:

- #EN%20FLEURS -> #EN_FLEURS
- #WWPW%202011 -> #WWPW_2011
- #MUSEÉ%20DU%20LOUVRE -> #MUSEE_DU_LOUVRE
- #FAIRYTALE%20ROAD -> #FAIRYTALE_ROAD

**By the way**

To hide your scroll to top link if not needed (e.g. at the top of your page) use this:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() !== 0) {
        $('#go_up').fadeOut();
    } else {
        $('#go_up').fadeIn();
    }
});
```

Hide it with css:

```
#go_up {display:none}
```

Comment: Very good suggestions, this is why I checked it, but they did not solve the problem in the question.

Comment: Thank you very much for this!  It's working pretty well.  One issue is that I have a bunch of code that kind of relies on those links being formatted as they are.  Why won't they work as they are?

Answer (score 1):

Your `$(this.hash).offset().top` does not always provide the value you expect, i.e. from the top of the `#main` div. If you scrolled to the bottom of the page and hit a link at the bottom, its `offset().top` will be relative on the screen, not absolute. Could be a negative value, for example. However, animate's scrollTop requires absolute scroll position.

One solution could be to do

```
$('#main').animate({scrollTop:
       $(this.hash).offset().top - $('#CONSTRUCTS').offset().top},
   3000, 'easeOutExpo');
```

where `#CONSTRUCTS` will work as the topmost element.

Depending on how dynamic your data is, you might want to replace it with anything at the top left corner of your #main.

There are many other ways to solve it.